# How to Reset Session Timeout in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to Reset Session Timeout when user is still active.

1. In my scenario my session timeout is 20 min., when session time is reached before 10 seconds
   i am showing a dialog to confirm the user as "Session is going to time out, Do you want to stay in ??". If user is click yes, i want to continue my session with again 20 minutes start from 21st minute, because as per requirement i am saving user session time in database table.
2. can we set timer for session timeout.

So, Please help me anyone, how to reset session timeout??

Comment: Look at this  http://www.pascarello.com/AjaxSessionTimer.aspx

Comment: You want a 10 minutes timeout, then a 20 minute timeout starting from the 21th minute???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write the jQuery script like:

```
 (document).ready(function () {


        $("#divdialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,

            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "Session Timeout",

            buttons: {
                Yes: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/<your controller>/SessionTimeout', // Redirects to action method for every 20 minutes.

                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "GET",
                        error: function () {
                            alert(" An error occurred.");
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#divdialog").dialog('close');
                            display("stop");

                        }
                    });
                },
                Logout: function () {
                    location.href = '/<your controller>/Logout';
                }
            }
        });


    });

    function myFunction() { // Fires every 20 minutes

        setInterval(function () {
            $("#divdialog").dialog('open');

        }, 1200000);
    }
```

and Add Action Method in your controller like:

```
  public ActionResult SessionTimeout()
    {

        Session.Timeout = Session.Timeout + 20;

        return Json("",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hope above technique helps you.

Comment: How would you check Session.Timeout for a change?  Meaning Session.Timeout turns to 15, or 10. I see Session.Timeout has a set value.  I am planning a set interval but need that know that time is the same as the SessionTimeout